# How to fill std::vector with data from another vector that meets some criteria

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a vector of points, and I need to get those which are at a distance less than a value from a given point.

I could do it with a simple loop, but is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `std::remove_copy_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(2);
    std::vector<int> v2;

    std::remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v2),
            std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(),5));

    std::copy (v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`remove_copy_if` will copy a sequence to an output iterator for each item which fails a predicate. In this case, the predicate is "x>5". There doesn't seem to be an equivalent `copy_if` for each item which passes a predicate test, but you can always negate a predicate with `std::not1`.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html

Answer (score 4):

as Philip and Beta suggest, here is a more general way, using a functor predicate.
you could use C++0x lambdas instead of a handwriten functor.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

struct FunctorPredicate : public std::unary_function<bool,int>
{
   bool operator() (int i)
   {
      // do what you want here, in our case: test greater than 5.
      return i > 5; 
   }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(2);
    std::vector<int> v2;

    FunctorPredicate functorPredicate;
    std::remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v2), functorPredicate);

    std::copy (v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

inheriting form std::unary_function defines the two following typedef:
argument_type at int and result_type at bool.

and in Cplusplus STL reference for [std::remove_copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/) there is another example with a simpler `std::function<bool (int)>`.

Comment: @Stephen Rolland: Can we also use std::partition?

Comment: @Philip Potter, you are right, it defines the STL type traits for this function... but I still haven't started to you use them in practice. I really should, and thank you for the remark.

Comment: @chubsdad, yes you can also use it with partition, look at this example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/

Comment: one other advantage of `std::unary_function` that you don't mention is that it lets you use `std::not1` to negate it.

Comment: that's a one (1) not an ell (l). It means "negate a predicate which takes 1 argument".

Comment: In C++0x, not only will you have lambdas, you'll also get a `copy_if` algorithm, which was apparently left out of the stdlib by oversight.

Comment: @uncleBens I don't understand, what this `copy_if` would bring more ?

Comment: Just that you wouldn't have to think about all the negations with `remove_copy_if` and can do a rather common operation in a straightforward way.

Comment: @uncle okay I understand, I'm gonna correct my answer with your proposal which I feel can be better

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian proposed the `boost::make_xxx_range` functions already, but I suggest going one step further. The boost::make_xxx_range alone are very cumbersome to use. Typically, you want to use boost::range ;)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost::lambda;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 2, 6, 10, 5, 2};
    std::vector<int> v2;
    int dist = 5;

    boost::push_back(v2, filter(v, _1 > dist));

    boost::copy(v2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maxim proposed the `boost::filter_iterator` already, but I suggest going one step further. The boost iterators alone are very cumbersome to use. Typically, you want to filter ranges, copy ranges, or search ranges. For every boost iterator, we have a utility function make_xxx_range like the following:

```
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

template< class Range, class Pred >
boost::iterator_range< boost::filter_iterator< Pred, typename boost::range_iterator<Range>::type > > 
make_filter_range( Range& rng, Pred p ) {
    return boost::make_iterator_range( boost::make_filter_iterator(pred, boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng)), boost::make_filter_iterator(pred, boost::end(rng), boost::end(rng)) );
}
```

Having that, the solution to your problem is trivial:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp> 
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    // fill vector
    std::vector<int> v2 = boost::copy_range< std::vector<int> >( 
        make_filter_range( v, boost::lambda::_1 > 5 );
}
```